# Plotting and preparing a list of points to get a function for Fourier Transform

Tags: plotting

I try to extract a series of points from a wave pattern, and I have manually identified the peaks and "lows" of the wave train on an interval, manually. Then I'd like to plot this, and analyse it.

The list is

```
disc = Piecewise[{{-5, 0}, {-4.8, 3}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4.2, 1}, {-4, 
    3.5}, {-3.8, 0}, {-3.5, 6}, {-3.1, 0}, {-3, -5.5}, {-2.8, 
    0}, {-2.5, 6}, {-2.1, 0}, {-1.8, -2.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.2, 
    5}, {-0.8, 0}, {-0.5, -8}, {-0.2, 0}, {0, 18}, {1/2, 
    0}, {2/3, -8}, {1, 0}, {4/3, 4}, {3/2, 0}, {1.6, -4}, {2, 
    3}, {2.5, -3}, {3, 3}, {3.2, -2}, {3.5, 2}, {3.8, -4}, {4.2, 
    0}, {4.5, 6}, {4.8, -5}, {5, 0}}]
```

However, two problems occur:

the last coordinate (5,0) results as "5,True" in the output, which is weird.

Then when trying to plot it using Listplot, I get "Piecewise::pairs: The first argument False of Piecewise is not a list of pairs." I wonder if "True" is the problem here.

Then this problems transfers to the next command: "ListPlot:Piecewise[{{-5.,0.},{-4.8,3.},{-4.5,1.},{-4.,3.5},{-3.8,0.},{-3.5,6.}
,{-3.1,0.},{-3.,-5.5},{-2.8,0.},{-2.5,6.},<<24>>},0.] is not a list 
of numbers or pairs of number""

However, if I load the points of the wave pattern as points:

```
points = {{-5, 0}, {-4.8, 3}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4.2, 1}, {-4, 3.5}, {-3.8, 
    0}, {-3.5, 6}, {-3.1, 0}, {-3, -5.5}, {-2.8, 0}, {-2.5, 6}, {-2.1,
     0}, {-1.8, -2.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.2, 5}, {-0.8, 
    0}, {-0.5, -8}, {-0.2, 0}, {0, 18}, {1/2, 0}, {2/3, -8}, {1, 
    0}, {4/3, 4}, {3/2, 0}, {1.6, -4}, {2, 3}, {2.5, -3}, {3, 
    3}, {3.2, -2}, {3.5, 2}, {3.8, -4}, {4.2, 0}, {4.5, 
    6}, {4.8, -5}, {5, 0}};
```

I can plot this,
using

```
ifun = Interpolation[points]
```

but I don't get it as a piecewise function, that I can later analyse using Fourier methods.

Any ideas how I can plot/prepare this as a piecewise function for DFT?

Thanks

Comment: (-1)  You're using `Piecewise` blindly, and the input of DFT (`Fourier`) is a `List`, not a `Piecewise` function. Once again, please read the document of `Piecewise` and `Fourier` to learn their usage. You should never guess the usage of unknown functions, and you should never use Wolfram|Alpha for any serious programming. (Yes, I see your deleted comment. )

Comment: Your definition of disc has wrong syntax. The correct syntax is: Piecewise[{{value, condition},...}], where condition is e.g. 1<x<=2

Comment: Daniel, I gather, so an example for the first point is {-5,0<x<0.5}.

Comment: "I gather, so an example for the first point is {-5,0<x<0.5}" No, your guess is wrong. For the last time: you should not guess the usage of unknown functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to extend function `disc` at $x<-5, x>5$. This is  one possible solution

```
points = {{-5, 0}, {-4.8, 3}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4.2, 1}, {-4, 3.5}, {-3.8, 
    0}, {-3.5, 6}, {-3.1, 0}, {-3, -5.5}, {-2.8, 0}, {-2.5, 6}, {-2.1,
     0}, {-1.8, -2.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.2, 5}, {-0.8, 
    0}, {-0.5, -8}, {-0.2, 0}, {0, 18}, {1/2, 0}, {2/3, -8}, {1, 
    0}, {4/3, 4}, {3/2, 0}, {1.6, -4}, {2, 3}, {2.5, -3}, {3, 
    3}, {3.2, -2}, {3.5, 2}, {3.8, -4}, {4.2, 0}, {4.5, 
    6}, {4.8, -5}, {5, 0}};
ListPlot[points, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
disc[x_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{points[[i, 2]], points[[i, 1]] > x}, {i, Length[points]}], 0]

Plot[disc[x], {x, -6, 6}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

```
dft = FourierTransform[disc[x], x, k]

Out[]= 1/(
 k Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) ((0. - 
     18. I) + (0. + 18. I) E^((0. - 0.2 I) k) - (0. + 
      2. I) E^((0. + 3. I) k) + (0. + 
      2. I) E^((0. + 3.2 I) k) - (0. + 
      3. I) E^((0. - 4.8 I) k) + (0. + 3. I) E^((0. - 5. I) k) - 
   16. Cos[0.583333 k] Sin[0.0833333 k] + 
   7. E^((0. - 4.1 I) k) Sin[0.1 k] - 
   5. E^((0. - 1.95 I) k) Sin[0.15 k] - 16. Cos[0.65 k] Sin[0.15 k] + 
   10. Cos[1.35 k] Sin[0.15 k] + 12. Cos[2.65 k] Sin[0.15 k] + 
   4. Cos[3.35 k] Sin[0.15 k] + 4. Cos[3.65 k] Sin[0.15 k] + 
   12. Cos[4.35 k] Sin[0.15 k] - 10. Cos[4.65 k] Sin[0.15 k] + 
   8. E^((0. + 1.16667 I) k) Sin[0.166667 k] + 
   6. E^((0. + 1.8 I) k) Sin[0.2 k] - 
   6. E^((0. + 2.25 I) k) Sin[0.25 k] + 6. Cos[2.75 k] Sin[0.25 k] + 
   2. E^((0. - 4.5 I) k)
     Sin[0.3 k] - (0. + 16. I) Sin[0.0833333 k] Sin[
     0.583333 k] + (0. + 16. I) Sin[0.15 k] Sin[
     0.65 k] - (0. + 10. I) Sin[0.15 k] Sin[1.35 k] + 
   Sin[0.05 k] (-11. E^((0. - 3.05 I) k) - 
      8. Cos[1.55 k] - (0. + 8. I) Sin[1.55 k]) - (0. + 12. I) Sin[
     0.15 k] Sin[2.65 k] + (0. + 6. I) Sin[0.25 k] Sin[
     2.75 k] + (0. + 4. I) Sin[0.15 k] Sin[3.35 k] - (0. + 20. I) Sin[
     0.15 k] Sin[3.65 k] + (0. + 12. I) Sin[0.15 k] Sin[
     4.35 k] - (0. + 10. I) Sin[0.15 k] Sin[4.65 k])

 LogLogPlot[Evaluate@Abs[dft], {k, 10^-5, 10^2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I will study this today.